# Y axis ticks display format in Google line chart

Tags: format, axis

I need Y axis ticks format in multiples of 500's

What I have is

http://i60.tinypic.com/104500w.jpg

What I need is

http://i58.tinypic.com/bfhod5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I added the below property to the graph:

vAxis:{ticks: [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500]}